# why next/link rendering twice? how to solve it?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a page inside pages so, if you go to direct URL then it will print console.log once and if you go there with  then it is printing twice.

Why it is happening?

I want to perform some task once per page.

```
<Link route={href} href={href}>
   <a href={href}>
     page to redirect
   </a>
</Link>
```

I already go through with this issue https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/253 but still I am not clear

I am using **next-routes** package for `<Link>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<Link to={href} href={href}>
   <a>
     page to redirect
   </a>
</Link>
```

remove `href` on `<a />` and replace `route` to `to` on `<Link/>`

Comment: Your code refers to `next/link` but I am using next-routes package for `<Link>`

Comment: sometimes it doesn't matter that console log displayed twice. it depends on you.